# Sql - No es posible usar una función de agregado con una expresión que contiene un agregado o una subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, while, subconsultas

Estoy teniendo este resultado cuando trato de ejecutar mi **SP** aúnque podría jurar que ya lo había hecho funcionar. Si alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo malo estaría muy agradecido.

> Line 166 [Batch Start Line 10]
>   No es posible usar una función de agregado con una expresión que contiene un agregado o una subconsulta.

```js
eclare @listaDePagos varchar(max) = ''
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ids') is not null DROP TABLE# ids

create table# ids([Id] int);
--SELECT * FROM Split('1,2,3,4', ',')

insert into# ids--estos son id 's de pagos
select *
  from Split(@listaDePagos, ',')

while (count((select id from# ids)) > 0) --Aqui es donde marca mi error :s
  begin
set @IdPago = (select top(1) id from# ids)

insert into PagoOrdenes
  (IdPago, Activo)
values(@IdPago, 1)

DELETE TOP(1) FROM# ids
end
```

Comment: Tienes que plantear la lógica que deseas usar. No queda claro, tienes un while pero no controlas su flujo.
Por otro lado, te sugiero que cuando recibas respuestas en tus preguntas (como en otros casos), retroalimentes a quienes te ayudaron, de ese modo la comunidad crece. Elige siempre la respuesta correcta en caso de que exista. Saludos

Comment: @ElenaLópez ya me contestaron mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` se utiliza dentro del select ya que es una función de agregado.

Reemplaza:

```
while (count((select id from# ids)) > 0)
```

Por:

```
while ((select count(id) from# ids) > 0)
```

Comment: Mientras haya registros en la tabla el while se estará ejecutando de forma infinita, no está controlando el flujo

Comment: @ElenaLópez, si notas al final del `WHILE`, el borra registros de la tabla temporal: `DELETE TOP(1) FROM# ids` por lo que al final la tabla siempre quedara vacía.

Comment: Cierto, obvié esa parte ;)